# Question on O365 - Planner

Tags: office-365, licensing

I am using O365 free license for non-profit orgs. Despite seeing it was launched I do not see it in my collection of apps. Is it because it is not provided for non-profits or it is not provided for the free license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in a similar situation - Microsoft support team confirmed to me that it was included in the non profit plan (E1) but as it is being rolled out in phases they haven't yet reached your tenant. Although the `Planner` tile is missing from the `O365` launcher - you should be able to access `Planner` via this url.

https://tasks.office.com

Comment: in my case I get this page after logging in
We're not ready for you yet.

We're still setting things up. Please try again later. 

8eabf69a-f864-4bc8-8da4-cc651006193c 

Date and Time: 11/3/2016 11:29:47 AM 

Planner Version: 16.0.7528.5001

Comment: The planner tile is now showing up in my O365 tenant.